# DATAGRIDVIEW (Allow User to Add Rows Row) is being set to blank when clicking off that row

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview and I have the allowusertoaddrows enabled and all of the data that is being inserted is within this but everything is inserted manually (on button click). The issue is that if a user clicks off this row it's set to blank - not by me. I'm thinking it's due to the data grid view thinking that the row has been inserted and then setting it to blank because if I click back in everything is still there but just hidden and I need to click on the cell to show it again.  Everything is being bound this way.

```
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY dept ASC";
                    m_myDT = m_Conn.GetDataTable(sSQL);

                    dgTableEntry.DataSource = m_myDT;
                    dgTableEntry.Columns[0].Visible = true;

                    dgTableEntry.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Home Department";
                    dgTableEntry.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Department Name";

                    dgTableEntry.Columns[1].Width = 150;
                    dgTableEntry.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

I'm just trying to prevent the text from being hidden for the time they are off the row.

Comment: Can you post the full code of the grid setup, and of the "button that does the add". I get the feeling that all that button should do is call EndEdit on the dgv, or that the button that is doing the add is incorrectly poking the data into the grid when it should be adding it to the datatable the grid is bound to

Comment: (Your Question doesn't easily make it clear whether you expect the user to type the data into the grid or into textboxes where you then transfer the data into the grid at the click of a button) (if the former, set "allow user to add rows" to true and ditch the textboxes. If the latter, set it false. You might also generate a better overall user experience if you bind your boxes and your grid to the datatable, via the same binding source, and let databibding manage the "transfer" into the grid